# Docusign : 400 Error "Unable to parse multipart body" when trying to create envelope from Template ID from UI5 application

Tags: api, sapui5, postman, docusignapi, http-status-code-400

We are trying to figure out whether `Docusign` can be used in productive scenarios for our client requirements.

We have a UI5 application which will be used to sign Documents. We have created a template in the demo instance of `Docusign`.

However when we are trying to create an envelope from the application we are getting `400 Error` `Unable to parse multipart body`. Now the same payload when used in POSTMAN application results in the envelope getting created successfully. The headers passed are also the same.

In Ui5 App :

```
var settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "/docusign/envelopes",
                "method": "POST",
                "timeout": 0,
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": "User DnVj27euWrCi4ANoMV5puvxVxYAcUCG3PlkUSpWpC08=, Organization 6ba64ce816dec995b17d04605e329a30, Element X4XuUq/T5UUh2o9xwaamZCCRwOKUCPr1Kv1Nj+qHPj0=",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "data": JSON.stringify({
                    "status": "sent",
                    "compositeTemplates": [{
                        "compositeTemplateId": "1",
                        "inlineTemplates": [{
                            "recipients": {
                                "signers": [{
                                    "email": "johndoe@testmail.com",
                                    "name": "John Doe",
                                    "recipientId": "1",
                                    "roleName": "Signer",
                                    "clientUserId": "12345",
                                    "tabs": {
                                        "textTabs": [{
                                            "tabLabel": "firstName",
                                            "value": "John"
                                        }, {
                                            "tabLabel": "lastName",
                                            "value": "Doe"
                                        }, {
                                            "tabLabel": "phoneNo",
                                            "value": "022-635363"
                                        }, {
                                            "tabLabel": "email",
                                            "value": "test@gmail.com"
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }]
                            },
                            "sequence": "1"
                        }],
                        "serverTemplates": [{
                            "sequence": "1",
                            "templateId": "0bf97611-a457-4e8e-ac7e-1593c17ba3f6"
                        }]
                    }]
                })
            };
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }.bind(this)).fail(function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }.bind(this));
```

In Postman :
[image: Successful POST]

[image: Headers]

Help would be greatly appreciated in resolving this issue.

Comment: compare the header values when sent from Postman and when called from your App. Above code has "Content-Type": "application/json" and this is not multipart, so share the exact log before hitting DocuSign. Or you can capture DS logs as explained by Larry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by directly using the Docusign API (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts). I was earlier using the SAP Openconnector to connect to Docusign.
https://api.openconnectors.eu3.ext.hanatrial.ondemand.com/elements/api-v2

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you stringify outside of the json settings and perhaps break your call down a little before placing everything in settings.

i.e. Try and re-shape your jquery ajax call:

```
var headers = {"Authorization": "User DnVj27euWrCi4ANoMV5puvxVxYAcUCG3PlkUSpWpC08=, Organization 6ba64ce816dec995b17d04605e329a30, Element X4XuUq/T5UUh2o9xwaamZCCRwOKUCPr1Kv1Nj+qHPj0=", "Content-Type": "application/json" };
var payload = JSON.stringify({
                "status": "sent",
                "compositeTemplates": [{
                    "compositeTemplateId": "1",
                    "inlineTemplates": [{
                        "recipients": {
                            "signers": [{
                                "email": "johndoe@testmail.com",
                                "name": "John Doe",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "roleName": "Signer",
                                "clientUserId": "12345",
                                "tabs": {
                                    "textTabs": [{
                                        "tabLabel": "firstName",
                                        "value": "John"
                                    }, {
                                        "tabLabel": "lastName",
                                        "value": "Doe"
                                    }, {
                                        "tabLabel": "phoneNo",
                                        "value": "022-635363"
                                    }, {
                                        "tabLabel": "email",
                                        "value": "test@gmail.com"
                                    }]
                                }
                            }]
                        },
                        "sequence": "1"
                    }],
                    "serverTemplates": [{
                        "sequence": "1",
                        "templateId": "0bf97611-a457-4e8e-ac7e-1593c17ba3f6"
                    }]
                }]
            });
$.ajax({
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "/docusign/envelopes",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": headers,
  "data": payload
});
```

I am sure this will lead you to your final "consolidated" answer.

Comment: Hi Bernard. I have tried the above code and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If the **exact same** JSON is being sent from Postman and from the UI5 application, then you'll get the same results. But you aren't, so something is different.

Probably the UI5 system is sending the API as a mime multi-part request, but isn't setting the content type for the JSON request part correctly.

To verify: use the [DocuSign API logger](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see what is being received by DocuSign. Compare between the request being sent from UI5 and from Postman.

To fix: you'll need to set additional UI5 parameters so the request is NOT sent as a multi-part mime message. Or send the multi-part message with the needed settings. See the [docs](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/requests-and-responses#multipart-form-requests) and see a [multi-part example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-curl/blob/master/examples/eg010SendBinaryDocs.sh).

PS PLEASE post an answer to your question with the solution to your problem (once you've found it) to help others in the future. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the very same issue recently, and almost decided to give up, but finally, I have managed to find a way to make it work!
The thing is that you need to execute the Ajax call in the following way:

```
_createEnvelops: function () {
            var deferred = $.Deferred();

            var oTemplateData = this._getTemplateData();
            var oFormData = new FormData();
            oFormData.append('envelope', JSON.stringify(oTemplateData));

            var settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": '/docusign/envelopes',
                "method": "POST",
                "data": oFormData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                "headers": {
                    "Authorization": sAuthToken
                }
            };

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            }.bind(this)).fail(function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            }.bind(this));

            return deferred;
        },
```

Maybe it will be useful for someone in the future ;)